# RSVP form for Facebook events from a Wordpress post?

Tags: facebook, forms, events, customization

Is there a way to add a RSVP form to a Facebook event in a Wordpress post?

(let's assume I have a website linked to a Facebook application and I want to publish public events I have published on a Facebook page also on my website, letting people RSVP from Wordpress and only from my FB page)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also working on this right now, I'd love if you post your final solution once you get there. Here are two tutorials that may help you.

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-status-and-rsvp-to-facebook-events-using-graph-api-fql/61/

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-facebook-events-using-graph-api-advanced/59/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook event widget is missing the RSVP functionality but you can use an external application for that http://evu.li/

or take a look ate [**`this`**](http://lab.neo-pangea.com/blog/2011/11/facepalmbook-api-an-event-rsvp-social-plugin-that-doesnt-exist-yet/)

Comment: The second solution looks interesting but I haven't understood how to implement it into Wordpress. Has this been made into a Wordpress plugin yet? Thank you

Comment: not that i know of but it should be simple.